# Create sub page of sub pages using "fake pages"

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

I found this [tutorial](http://www.placementedge.com/blog/create-post-sub-pages/) to make so called fake pages, so I could dynamically create pages with custom fields. It works very well, but I need to tweak it to fit my needs.

Like if for example a book have reviews from different sources:

> `mysite.com/books/to-kill-mockingbird/reviews/id-for-review`

This mean that **`to-kill-mockingbird`** is the slug for post type book and **`id-for-review`** is the slug for post type reviews. I can easily get this to work by removing **`books/to-kill-mockingbird`**, and just have **`mysite.com/reviews/id-for-review`**, but I prefer to have the full url.

Any suggestions?

I'm trying to create a new rewrite rule that puts the `id-for-review` into a query variable. I have added `$review-id` for that purpose.

Here's the rule I tried to make

```
if ($slug == 'reviews') {
           $newrules['books/([^/]+)/' . $slug . '/([^/]+)/?'] = 'index.php?book=$matches[1]&fpage=' . $slug . '&review-id=$matches[2]';
           $newrules['books/([^/]+)/' . $slug . '/?$'] = 'index.php?book=$matches[1]&fpage=' . $slug;
        }
        else
        {
           $newrules['books/([^/]+)/' . $slug . '/?$'] = 'index.php?book=$matches[1]&fpage=' . $slug;
        }
```

I have a template named single-book.php where the correct template is being used:

```
$current_fp = get_query_var('fpage');
$review-id = get_query_var('review-id');

if (!$current_fp) {
        get_template_part( 'single', 'book-index' );
    } else if ($current_fp == 'books') {
    if (!$review-id) {
        get_template_part( 'single', 'book-reviews' );
        }
        else
        {
        get_template_part( 'single', 'book-review' );
        }
    };
```

If I now go to /books/to-kill-mockingbird/reviews/, it uses the template for listing all reviews. But when I go to a review, it seems to use the standard WordPress template.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @Ben I've tried so many things, I thought it would be easier and less confusing to write them in the question. I have tried to change the rule, but as far as I know, it should be working the way it is now. I have tried to do changes in the template, but I get a "page not found" error if I have something after **/reviews/**, so template is not being used.

Comment: Can you please show us your `.htaccess` then?

Comment: @Ben Of course. Added into the question.

Comment: What are you using to alter the URL? Normally those rules are added as parts of the `.htaccess` file - but I can't see any relevant rules here. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: After reading the tutorial, could you post *your* code that you wrote, having adapted the code in the tutorial?

Comment: Right now I'm using the exact code as in the tutorial because I have been pretty far out with my attempts, and really can't see why that shouldn't work when I read the rule (line 28). It works for book/name-of-book/reviews, but not book/name-of-book/reviews/id-for-review. I'm a bit new to coding for Wordpress, but doesn't the /?$ represent the ID?

Comment: @Ben I have added the rewrite rule I tried to make into my question.

Comment: @janlindso Is the `$slug == 'review'` just a question typo?

Comment: @MackieeE Not really at the time, and I wrote the reason below the code. Anyway, I have managed to get a bit further, and have updated my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I came closer to the answer than I thought, after some tweaking and editing of my question. Most of my code is now correct.

Here's the rules that needs to put replaced in the example from the tutorial. This is put inside the foreach loop, and creates two rules for 'reviews'.

```
if ($slug == 'reviews') {
           $newrules['books/([^/]+)/' . $slug . '/([^/]+)/?'] = 'index.php?book=$matches[1]&fpage=' . $slug . '&review-id=$matches[2]';
           $newrules['books/([^/]+)/' . $slug . '/?$'] = 'index.php?book=$matches[1]&fpage=' . $slug;
        }
        else
        {
           $newrules['books/([^/]+)/' . $slug . '/?$'] = 'index.php?book=$matches[1]&fpage=' . $slug;
        }
```

Now inside the single-books.php template, use this to get correct template:

```
$current_fp = get_query_var('fpage');
$review-id = get_query_var('review-id');

if (!$current_fp) {
        get_template_part( 'single', 'book-index' );
    } else if ($current_fp == 'books') {
    if (!$review-id) {
        get_template_part( 'single', 'book-reviews' );
        }
        else
        {
        get_template_part( 'single', 'book-review' );
        }
    };
```

Now inside single-book-review.php template, you use this to get the post data based on the slug from the query var:

```
$review_id = get_query_var('review-id');

$post = get_page_by_path( $review_id, OBJECT, 'review' )
```

Also remember to go to **Settings -> Permalinks** and click save when you change the rule, to flush the rules.